# backslash replacement issue in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I could not get why this simple replacement logic is failing. Snowflake is treating `\` as escape character, and is replacing it before even i try to add double backslash `\\`.

All of the below are not working or err out. Can You pleae help.

Input='target\SEGMENT.sql'... By the way this is coming from a variable in dbt, and snowflake is inserting this as 'targetSEGMENT.sql' into my target. I am trying to avoid that \ replacement and want it as is.

```
SELECT REPLACE('target\SEGMENT.sql', '\\', '\\\\') FROM DUAL;
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('target\SEGMENT.sql', '\\', '__TEMP__'), '__TEMP__', '\\\\') FROM DUAL;
SELECT TRANSLATE('target\SEGMENT.sql', '\\', '\\\\') FROM DUAL;
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('target\SEGMENT.sql', '[\]]', '\\\\') FROM DUAL;
```

Actual Output:
targetSEGMENT.sql

Expected output:
target\SEGMENT.sql

Below is the dbt code as per users request.

```
UPDATE ...
SET
    DATE= ...,
    UPDATED_BY= '{{model.path}}',
    UPDATE_DATE= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
WHERE NAME='...' ;  
'''
```

Comment: Your expected output is identical to your input - which doesn't seem to make sense?

Comment: Try selecting just the initial strings and you'll see that none of them have backslashes in them (you used them to escape the S). So? Use double backslash in the initial string literals.

Comment: Show the dbt code you're using. I'm willing to bet that your insert statement doesn't use parameters.  You're either using parameters, or you're using literals. And, as you've found, a literal with `\S` is interpreted as escape-S (before it is ever a data string).  If you want a literal with a backslash it MUST be escaped (double backslash). If you don't want to use double backslash, you MUST use parameters.

Comment: @MatBailie Added dbt code at the end. Its an update statemet actually.

Comment: Quote : and snowflake is ***inserting*** this as 'targetSEGMENT.sql' into my target

Comment: Your query shows that you are using string substitution in to your query. That means you're using literals. This is how literals behave. There is no changing it. If you want different behaviour, don't substitute your data directly in to your SQL string, use parameters / prepared statements instead.

Comment: Your code is incomplete and does not show how you execute the query. Please read [mre] and [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952) and edit your question to show code we can run. Then we may be able to show you how to use parameters / prepared statements.

Comment: The input value you have in your SQL statements is 'target\SEGMENT.sql'. The expected output you’ve given is ‘ target\SEGMENT.sql’. These are identical so your question makes no sense as you’ve written it

Comment: @NickW The literal `'target\SEGMENT.sql'` evaluates to the string `targetSEGMENT.sql`. This happens because the OP's code substitutes the string `target\SEGMENT.sql` directly into a SQL statement. So, the DBMS processes the `'\'` as an escape character and the table ends up with `targetSEGMENT.sql` in it.  *(In short, the question states that they're **not** getting the expected output, and repeatedly stating "that makes no sense" completely ignores empirical observations.)*

Comment: @NickW For example, see https://dbfiddle.uk/qWNDIhjJ Then please try to be more helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In snowflake, we can have dollar-quoted strings (delimited by $$) that allow you to include any characters, including special characters and backslashes, literally within the string. These characters won't be interpreted as escape sequences.

dbt example:

```
UPDATE <my table>
SET
    DATE= ...,
    UPDATED_BY= $${{model.path}}$$,
    UPDATE_DATE= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
WHERE NAME=<some value> ;
```

Another simple example-

```
SELECT $$target\SEGMENT.sql$$ FROM DUAL
```

Comment: as an aside, you don't need to include `FROM DUAL` so `SELECT $$target\SEGMENT.sql$$ ` is valid in snowflake, make things just simpler given DUAL is really just an Oracle thing.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim Yeah I know. I am just addicted adding a table name at the end, so I dont feel like my query is incomplete or hanging :)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to discuse is you have the text `target\SEGMENT.sql`. To get into a SQL database via the SQL parser (the thing that reads `SELECT 1;`) you need to escape it correctly:

```
SELECT 'target\SEGMENT.sql' as text_wrong, 
    'target\\SEGMENT.sql' as text_correct;
```

gives:

[image]

Then the next thing to think about is "how is DBT" sending data to the database. Some systems like ODBC send strings in a binary format, and other system send a "text string". If you are parsing a text string, it will need to be parser safe before it leaves your side. Which means you need to do the `replace(str, '\\','\\\\')` on the DBT host, not on the DB, because once it has gotten to the DB it has been parsed.

Now there are other things to also understand about the parser, so if we base64 encode your input (I did it via notepad++) we get `dGFyZ2V0XFNFR01FTlQuc3Fs` which we can show is parser safe:

```
SELECT 'dGFyZ2V0XFNFR01FTlQuc3Fs' as b64,
    base64_decode_string(b64) as text_correct;
```

[image]

but if we did want to do some REPLACE or REGEXP and talk about the slash, those need to be escaped also, thus to make a string that is in the database safe (aka escape the escapes) we have to:

```
SELECT 'dGFyZ2V0XFNFR01FTlQuc3Fs' as b64,
    base64_decode_string(b64) as text_correct,
    replace(text_correct, '\\', '\\\\') as parse_safe;
```

[image]

Thus if you want to build a SQL stored procedure that builds a REGEXP, that has an escaped slash, the stored procedure is PARSED to enter it, it is PARSED to run it and a REGEXP it has in it is PARSED, and thus you can need to put 8 slashes, just to talk about one at the extreme...